# NiMH battery at 660mV, is it trash or good?

Tags: nimh

An AAA battery of type NiMH is only at 660mV (unloaded).
Can it still be charged and used or should I throw it away*?

Some more details:

The battery comes in a 2 pack. The other battery has about 1.2V. The pack was opened and stored in my drawer for a year or so. I probably used one of them, that's why it is "empty", but honestly I don't remember.

I will try to charge them (both, as my charger only works with pairs).

* of course to a proper bin for old batteries

Comment: Charge it and see. It's not like LiPo where such a deep discharge is likely to cause a fire next time you charge it. However, it may not accept its full charge, or if it does, it may not hold it very well. Or, it might be OK.

Comment: Charge it, and measure the capacity?

Comment: Unlike Lithium based cells, Nickel based cells like NiCd and NiMh generally do not suffer damage when discharged to a very low voltage. So indeed, just charge it and see what it does. Changes are, it might still be OK.

Comment: If its been idle for a long time, cycle it a couple of times before deciding if its junk.

Comment: Even taking down to 0v should not permanently damage a NiMH, charge gently, cycle a few times, and see what you get. Reverse charging (could happen to one cell in a series pack if deeply discharged) *will* damage the electrodes. Low voltage on a lithium cell is a no no.

Answer (score 1):

Standard NiMH batteries have fairly high leakage and will lose most of their charge over a few months. However leakage reduces as voltage drops, so even after a year it should still have some voltage left. Individual cells in a pack may leak at different rates as well as having slightly different capacities, so over time their voltages will diverge.

In my experience a 'new' NiMH cell that reads over 0.5V is usually OK. However it will probably need 3-5 charge-discharge cycles to reach full capacity, whereas if your other cell has already had some cycles it will initially have higher capacity.

The problem you have is how to bring both cells up to full capacity when your charger only works with pairs. The answer is to charge them in pairs, but discharge each one individually. That way the lower capacity cell can't be damaged by over-discharge.

Answer (score 0):

The comments given to you are good and appropriate.

That said - I would recommend that you charge each of the cells individually. Then do a re-condition cycle to each of the cells individually.

The most probable cause of your problem is that the cells don't have the same capacity.

Comment: Isn't an AAA battery a single cell?